# How do I obtain the sub-second portion of an NSDate?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Using [OS X v10.10.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite) (Yosemite) and Xcode 6.1.1.

I feel I must be overlooking something simple and obvious, but I just can't see it. I'm parsing the parts of an NSDate whose value is just the system date.

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *systemCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [systemCalendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:currentSystemDate];
```

I can then get the seconds as

```
NSInteger seconds = [dateComponents second];
```

but this only gives me the whole number of seconds. I need the decimal portion of the seconds as well. According to the documentation. I can use

```
NSInteger nanos = [dateComponents nanoseconds];
```

to get the "number of nanosecond units for the receiver". It doesn't work however. The method is legitimate, but *nanos* is set to the maximum value of NSInteger. This is (I presume) because I have not supplied a suitable constant in the components method. The problem with that is that there is no NSNanosecondCalendarUnit constant and I cannot find any suitable alternative.

I could construct a new date using the date components and then subtract the two to get an NSTimeInterval which I believe will give me what I need, but I'm finding it hard to believe that there isn't a more straightforward way to get it.

Is there a simple straightforward way in Cocoa to calculate the sub-second portion of an NSDate or do I have to use the approach I just suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the older deprecated names for the components. The new names include `NSCalendarUnitNanosecond`. Take a look at `NSCalendar.h`, and you'll see the old and new names.

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [systemCalendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond|NSCalendarUnitNanosecond) fromDate:currentSystemDate];
```